# Website has spacing at the top in Safari 5.1.7

Tags: css, safari

http://goo.gl/28W72

When I view the website on safari, I see white space at the top of it. How can I take that out? I already am using css reset?? where is that spacing coming from?

[image]

Comment: Hi, Im using Safari 5.1.7 but I don't see this white space. Is this right at the top of the page?

Comment: exactly! it's right at the top. I am using 5.1.7

Comment: No sorry it doesn't appear in my browser.

Comment: I'm definitely not seeing that much white space! I thought we were only talking about 1px or so!

Comment: nope... it's crazy.. I am on windows 7 machine.. maybe that's why.

Comment: Ahhh ok I'm on a mac ... so that wasn't as fair test as i thought it was :) I'll start up my virtual and have a look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above this isn't appearing in my version of Safari 5.1.7. Please see picture below.

[image]

I would say this is an issue with your browser alone.

I would suggest -

• Clearing cache

• Resetting safari settings.

• Any extra plugins you have installed.

• I notice your tool bar looks slightly different, do you have any themes installed?

Have you tried using the web inspector to see if there is anything in that space?

Comment: I did all you said nothing changed. I checked on 2 other computers, they don't have the problem I have either so I am guessing something is off with the safari I got on my pc.

Comment: No problem glad I was of some help... yeah I've just tried this on my win7 safari and it doesn't seem to be there either. A bit of an extreme solution but maybe worth reinstalling safari :)